# Movement towards a direction oscillates when near target

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I have a very simple animation: http://jsfiddle.net/k5uf9bm5/

I have a rectangle (the player), and when I click on the document somewhere the player moves towards that target position.

The problem is that it can't quite reach it -- it oscillates back and forth endlessly.

This is pretty weird to me because it's always worked in other languages, and in fact is similar to implementations other games use. What could *possibly* be the problem eluding me?

Here's the code, for question completion's sake:

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var pos = {x: 0, y: 0}
var target = null
var $player = $("#player")

$(document).click(function(e) { target = {x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY} })

function update() {
    $player.css({left: pos.x + 'px', top: pos.y + 'px'})

    if(target) {
        var dx = target.x - pos.x
        var dy = target.y - pos.y
        var len = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
        dx /= len
        dy /= len

        /*var theta = Math.atan2(target.y - pos.y, target.x - pos.x)
        var dx = Math.cos(theta)
        var dy = Math.sin(theta)*/

        pos.x += dx
        pos.y += dy
    }

    setTimeout(update, 25)
}

update()
</script>
<style>
#player {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15; height: 15;
  background-color: black;
}
</style>
<body>
<body>
  <div id="player">x</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing a break condition. `len` contains the distance to target.

```
 var len = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

In your code you always move towards the target at unit vectors.. now assume the distance to the target is 3.5 units.. then you will oscillate around the target forever.
At step 4 you will overshoot by 0.5. Then at step 5 undershoot by 0.5 and so on forever..

You should make sure that if `len <1` then don't divide by it just make pos equals target position and then stop calling update.

This will also solve a possible divide by zero if len == 0

Comment: Thanks! Solved it like that (if len < speed (in this case 1), set pos to target).

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of an answer I gave some time ago.
Have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21274650/1698987) :).

The question was about angles, but if you'll look at his fiddle, you'll see his tracking was oscillating as well.
In my Fiddle, it doesn't (well, it also accelerates and decelerates, and has nicer turning I think ... ).

More specific, I had something like this:

```
// time to decelerate
if (distance <nextDecleration ){
   nextDecleration = decelerate(distance);
 }
// within 10 px, do nothing
else if (distance -10 < nextDecleration)       { 
  // do nothing
}
// bigger than 10, accelerate
else {
  nextDecleration = accelerate(distance);
}
```

which translates to: if you're in the vecitiny of the point, that's good enough. stop there.